# rundeck git-plugin failed with error "No such property: op for class: com.rundeck.plugin.GitCloneWorkflowStep"

Tags: rundeck

I want to use this plugin:  git-plugin -> https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/git-plugin

but i'm face to an issue. When i use it, it failed with that error:

```
Workflow result: , step failures: {1=PluginFailed: No such property: op for class: com.rundeck.plugin.GitCloneWorkflowStep
```

However, the installation is quite easy and straight forward.
Just download .jar and put it in /var/lib/rundeck/libext folder with good rights.

I have already used it with success in another instance of rundeck.

But here, i don't know why it doesn't work.

Any tips or advice ?

regards

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced the issue:

```
[2020-04-07 09:15:48.511] ERROR ExecutionUtilService --- [eduler_Worker-7] Execution failed: 8 in project ProjectGITHUB: [Workflow result: , step failures: {1=PluginFailed: No such property: op for class: com.rundeck.plugin.GitCloneWorkflowStep}, status: failed]
```

You need to put the path of your repo (Git URL textbox) on the Git Clone workflow step in this way (i used HTTPS way to connect):

```
https://user@github.com/user/test.git
```

Instead of:

```
https://user@github.com/user
```

(or an inexistent URL address)

[Here](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/git-plugin#repo-settings-1) you can see how to configure it. And here a [Related](https://github.com/rundeck-plugins/git-plugin/issues/15) thread.